# Заполнить ячейку значением из ячейки на несколько индексов меньше: pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Народ, прошу помочь с Pandas (картинка для примера в экселе).
Есть датафрейм: номер рейса, дата вылета, количество купленных билетов, дней до вылета.
За день до вылета ни на одном рейсе продаж не было, но данную строку заполнить надо.
Количество купленных билетов заполнить не проблема - fillna(0).
А вот как заполнить номер рейса и дату вылета?
Важно: это только выборка с двумя рейсоднями, по факту во фрейме их гораздо больше.

UPD: заполнить внутри смог, но как быть с верхними пустыми значениями, где много нанов, и shift вставляет тот же самый nan?

```py
dct = {'Дней_до_вылета': [4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       'Рейс': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'x','y',np.nan, np.nan, 'x','y'],
       'Дата_вылета': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '2022-10-17', '2022-10-20', np.nan, np.nan, '2022-10-17', '2022-10-20'],
       'Купленные_билеты': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на два индекса меньше это стабильно или нет? И приведите кусок данных побольше и в воспроизводимой форме - чтобы можно было скопировать код и поэкспериментировать. Так то навскидку будет что-то наверное типа `fillna(df['Рейс'].shift(2))`, но нужно пробовать

Comment: я думаю, надо группировать по полю "дней до вылета", и заполнять отсутствующие рейсы с 0-й продажей

Comment: CrazyElf помог с первой частью, появилась вторая - UPD

Comment: На дополнение к вопросу: а теперь попробуйте тоже самое с `shitf(-2)`. Несколько раз, пока не останется `NA`. Но вообще у меня впечатление, что вы воюете с последствиями, а нужно воевать с причиной. Откуда вообще у вас там `NA` взялись?

Comment: Дней до вылета всего 120 - это искусственный период. По факту у рейса могут быть продажи, начиная с 37 дня до вылета и далее: например, 37-36-30-10-9... Но заполнить нужно именно фрейм длиной 120. Причина, видимо, в неоптимальном sql запросе. Думал, быстрее подшаманить в пандасе будет